# How should i use the extracted data from web scraping?

Tags: r, database, csv, google-chrome, web-scraping

I am learning web scraping and I have a question. I hope somebody has time to answer my question.

I have a large dataset of cars, I only have make/model/year/fuel and I need engine capacity. If I extract data from the website, I will have a CSV file with different technical attributes;

my question is: should I search manually in this extracted file to find for example the first make/model in my dataset and find the related engine capacity?

is there a way to integrate extracted CSV file with my dataset to find engine capacity for each make/model faster?

Are there other ways to find the capacity engine without data scraping?

thank you for your help

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a reproducible example and code that you have tried refer https://de.wikisource.org/wiki/Die_Gartenlaube_(1853)/Heft_1

Comment: I do not have codes for this question.

Comment: Can you give the url of the website?